# Google Custom Site Search Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, search-engine

To add additional Autocomplete selections to our Google Custom Site Search Engine, Google has a link to "Upload your autocomplete files in XML"

Is there any guidance on the format of this XML file?  We want to make sure that we are able to add the Autocompletes successfully.

Answer (score 2):

It takes a bit of hunting through the Google documentation jungle, but I think this might be what you are looking for:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/queries#auto